# docker image rm command doesn't work and just stops

Tags: docker

Disk usages of some of my servers are 100%, so I'm trying to remove unusing docker images for additional space.

Other than one server, `docker image rm` command worked fine.

But for a certain server, the command doesn't work.

```
USER@HOST:/home1:> sudo docker rmi DOCKER_IMAGE_ID
```

Nothing happens after this command, and the command doesn't exit.

I added `-debug` option, but it's the same, no information printed.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have problem only with `docker image rm` or there are other docker commands that are "hanging"? I had problems with older version of Docker with "hanging" even on `docker ps` so the only solution was to restart the docker daemon (which will restart all containers on the host)

Comment: This is related to docker maintenance and management, not to programming. Therefore it is off-topic here and you will get much better chances to get this answered on https://superuser.com

Comment: @jordanvrtanoski `docker ps` works well.  @Zeitounator Okay, thanks for your comment.